# Try-Finally vs Thread.BeginCriticalRegion

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

As I understand it, a finally block must be completed before a thread abort can take effect. For what purpose should `Thread.BeginCriticalRegion` be used instead, risking termination of the appdomain?

Example:

```
try
{
}
finally
{
    CriticalOperation();
}
```

or

```
Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
CriticalOperation();
Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
```

Comment: `Thread.BeginCriticalRegion` doesn't protect against `Thread.Abort`

Comment: There is a very long article here on the working of Critical Regions http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/06/14/429181.aspx

Comment: I've read it, and it appears to target a similar problem, hence my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it very simple, `try... finally...` do protect against `Thread.Abort` (the `finally` part is fully protected and can't be interrupted/will always be executed), while `Thread.BeginCriticalRegion()` only give some metainformation to the runtime of .NET:

From https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/archive/blogs/bclteam/constrained-execution-regions-and-other-errata-brian-grunkemeyer

> Critical regions don't really do much.

...

> The first effect for critical regions is a way of informing the CLR that a lock is being held by a block of managed code

(note that this is only information... what the runtime does is its problem. There is no guarantee here)

> The second effect is that memory allocations within that block of code are marked as appdomain-critical.

and then it explain that the runtime should give priority to memory allocation to that block of code... so other meta-information for the runtime without guarantees for the programmer

Comment: So `Thread.BeginCriticalRegion` should only be used in conjunction with locks?

Comment: @toplel32 The `Thread.BeginCriticalRegion` should only be used if you work for Microsoft :-) All this mumbo jumbo about `Thread.BeginCriticalRegion` is probably snake oil not documented and implemented in secret ways that no one knows :-) The `try... finally` instead is very real and very practical and very working :-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski It was built for the SQL Server CLR engine, so probably yes :-), because that is the .NET engine, not the SQL CLR engine

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski from the article I linked *First, I must summarize our escalation policy for a host like SQL Server.* and so on speaking about the SQL Server problems

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, you're right, SQL server does some weird stuff.

Comment: In a class designed for multithreading support, is it conventional to regularly use an empty `Try` block with a `Finally` to make global changes? Is it reasonable to expect a thread abort in the first place?

Comment: @toplel32 I think no, because if there is an exception during the class initialization then the class won't be initialized and nothing will be returned by the `new` (the exception will be during the `new`), so the object will be GC (no references of the object exist). You do the try { // nothing } finally { ... } trick when you want to be sure multiple operations are executed together or not executed (this doesn't guarantee atomicity, but do help guaranteeing all or nothing) or when you have cleaning code that is very important that is executed

Comment: Please note that the finally block is not guaranteed to run. ""If the exception is not caught, execution of the finally block depends on whether the operating system chooses to trigger an exception unwind operation."" It depends on the application is designed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc793966.aspx